# What does "Use FEST assertions instead" mean in Robolectric's API documentation?

Tags: android, robolectric

I want to assert that the background resource of a view is indeed R.drawable.X

So I was thinking of writing something like this:

```
    ShadowLinearLayout ll = (ShadowLinearLayout) Robolectric.shadowOf(viewHolder.container);
    Assert.assertEquals(R.drawable.X, ll.getBackgroundResourceId());
```

But http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowView.html#getBackgroundResourceId%28%29 says that this method is depreciated, with the comment: Use FEST assertions instead

What is the suggested way of writing these kinds of assertions?

Comment: While we're at it, why does getBackgroundResourceId() returns -1 :(

Comment: What version of Robolectric are you using? Fest assertions make it nicer to write view assertions. https://github.com/square/fest-android

Comment: I am using robolectric-2.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! So instead of shadowing the viewgroup, I shadowed the Drawable instead, which holds the correct resource ID. Here's my code:

```
    ShadowDrawable background = Robolectric.shadowOf(viewHolder.container.getBackground());
    Assert.assertEquals(R.drawable.X, background.getCreatedFromResId());
```